# on mouseover display the content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a ui-dialog container on the left with each dialog having their id's or own title, on mouseover i want it to display their title and on mouse out display none.

Can anybody help me out?

Cheers
Jeev

Comment: where is ur coding? and what you have tried?

Comment: can you show what you tried..?

Comment: <div id="dialog_window_minimized_container"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('#dialog_window_1').style.display = 'block';"></div>

Comment: I am very new to jquery, so i am not able to use it properly.If the items where static then mouseover would ve been simple, but dialog will be created on runtime with user-defined title , and on mouse-over must display the same dialog title.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and reproduce the issue over there..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.dialog-container .dialog').hover(function(){
    $('.header').text($(this).attr('title'));//here shows the title of hovered dialog
}, function(){
    $('.header').text("");
});
```

Or you can improve this snippet, showing title in floating absolute div on the right side of each dialog.

Comment: i am not sure how to use your code in mine #dialog_window_minimized_container is the id of the container,'#' + div_id is the id of the new dialog created,and what are .header?? how do i use it?

Comment: '.header' is a div, where you want your title should be shown in. To attach handlers to all dialogs you have to use some class which presents in all dialogs. If you create dialogs dynamically, you should attach hover event with ON method http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery:

```
$("#dialog").hover(function(){
  $("#dialogContainer").show();
}, function(){
  $("#dialogContainer").hide();
});
```

Supposingly there exists elements with id of "dialog" and "dialogContainer" and this basicly says: on mouse enter show dialogContainer and on mouse leave - hide it.

Comment: i tried with this, but it's not working  $("#dialog_window_minimized_container ").hover(function(){
  $('#' + div_id).show();
}, function(){
  $('#' + div_id).hide();
});

Answer (score 0):

since you have tagged jquery

hope you have included the `jquery.js` file

you can give...

```
$('#dialog_window_minimized_container').hover(function(){
$('#dialog_window_1').css('display','block');
});
```

You will have the div as

```
<div id="dialog_window_minimized_container"></div>
```

**NOTE** :- You can use one id once in a page. ie, it should be Unique

Hope This Helps

Comment: ya i have included , and the div id is the same too.

Comment: can you replicate the issue in jsfiddle

Comment: i am trying to replicate the issue, as i am new i am finding it hard,and also i cant even post the screenshot here :(

Comment: no need to post the screenshot just save and a new url will be generated. paste that url over here..

Comment: still i am not able to create the fiddle :( the dialog is not being created there :(

Comment: Re you using mozilla firefox.?  are you seeing any error in the console of the firebug.

Comment: no.. i am using chrome and in it's debugger it's not showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $('#dialog').mouseover(function() {
       $("#dialogContainer").html($(this).attr('title'));
       $("#dialogContainer").show();
    });
    $('#dialog').mouseout(function(){
        $("#dialogContainer").hide();
    });
```

Comment: $('#dialog_window_minimized_container').mouseover(function() {
       $('#' + div_id).show();
    });
    $('#dialog_window_minimized_container').mouseout(function(){
        $('#' + div_id).hide();
    }); this didn't work either. :(